# How does my app tell if the current date is the real current date?

Tags: android, time

My goal is to create a version of the app that will expire after a certain date has passed. I want the time to expire at an absolute date, not a relative date,

Hence my app uses uses this code to check the current time:

```
Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

However, the user can manipulate this by changing their Date & Time settings.

Question:
How does my app tell if the user has manipulated their Date Time? 
or
How do I tell if the user has set the "automatic" Date Time setting?

Can you suggest the simplest way to check the internet for the current time?

Comment: how important is this expiration? Changing the current time on your phone affects lots of apps such as the calendar aso so I guess most users won't bother. Perhaps you can live with one or a few cheaters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each time your app is starts or exits save the current datetime. If next time the system date is an earlier value then you know the time has been tampered with.

You can't have a perfect solution, only if you have internet access. If you do, then there are a million ways you can ckeck for the time, or even call back to your server to check whether the trial license is still valid.

One way to check for internet time is making a simple request to an HTTP server. For example to google (you should use your own server for this).

Request:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2011 16:04:48 GMT
Expires: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 16:04:48 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

As you can see all HTTP servers report back teir current system date in the `Date` header.

But then again, this does not matter at all. If Internet connection is essential for your software to work you can use online license check on your own server. If not, then users can turn their connection off with the push of a button while using it.

Comment: Won't work for users who change the system time before they install the app.

Comment: Yes it will. It is totally irrelevant what time their clock shows when they start the program for the first time. Once they start it they will be able to use it for 30 (your choice) days. - The only way to trick this is to write down the time ech time they exit the program and next time when they start it, they set the clock one minute after the last time they exited. Doing this routine each time they start and close your program would contradict the very reason they bought an Android device: convenience.

Comment: I want the time to expire at an absolute date, not a relative date, otherwise they can just keep re-installing the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can access to the real time throw Network Time Protocol. You can see the definition in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)