# Trial period for app

Tags: android, time-trial

I'm implementing an app which works with a monthly subscription.
Now, I need to validate whether the app has been paid for this month, for this I need to make regular checks against a server.

The question is, what is a correct way to validate, say, once per month? I could validate dates and verify that a month has passed, but the user could easily change the device's date time.
I thought of having a usage counter, and after X usages, require the user to go online and connect to the server.

Is this a correct approach? or is there a safe way to obtain the system date and being sure that the user has not tampered with it?

Thank you.

Comment: How could a user spoof the date if you are doing it server side? Just validate if they paid server side every time they open the app

Comment: Not good, forcing the user to go online every time they open the app is not acceptable, this app is supposed to work on the countryside, for people who work with cattle and such, and internet connections are not always available when working on the field. I need a way to force the user to connect, but only once in a while, not everytime.

Comment: I wouldnt worry about people spoofing the system clock. I believe its only possible on rooted devices and done through adb. Not many, if any will have capability of doing that.

Comment: Hmm, but I can change the system time whenever I want on a non rooted device, what do you mean?

Comment: If your talking about through the actual phone options. That is not the System Time. It does not reflect what your code returns

Comment: So the system time can differ from the date displayed? I need to read more on this then, where is that system date obtained from (I mean, how does Android know the date)? can it be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it by validating dates. Save the date in a sqlite db and every months (or whatever you like) check the license. Each time your app is starts or exits save the current datetime. If next time the system date is an earlier value then you know the time has been tampered with.

Took part of my answer here: [How does my app tell if the current date is the real current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247899/how-does-my-app-tell-if-the-current-date-is-the-real-current-date)

Comment: Sounds good to save the date of each time the user opens the app, verify for duplicates, or a new date earlier than the rest (meaning the date's been tampered with). Thanks.